# Enable modules on nginx and ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have a server with nginx installed. I'd like to enable modules (specifically ngx_http_map_module). Ok questions:

1) How can I check if the module is installed or not?
2) What is the workflow for installing the module? The only way is to stop nginx, remove it and recompile with the new module?
3) Stopping nginx isn't an option as there is a live website already. Any other options for adding modules?

Comment: `map` module is enabled by default. You could list all builded modules with `nginx -V` command. You don't need to stop nginx to recompile it with other modules, but I guess you even don't need to recompile it.

Comment: Ubuntu has several versions of nginx with different set of modules enabled.

Comment: The command: `nginx -V` shows this http://pastebin.com/z1cunc0p where I don't see the map module enabled... or not?

Comment: It's build by default. And I highly doubt if it even could be disabled.

Comment: Anyway, what is the real problem? Show us your code and errors

Comment: I created a blacklist with the spam referers and it worked, just wondering about the `nginx -V` command. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `http_map_module` is [compiled/enabled by default](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/auto/options#L81)

So you shouldn't have any problems using it. Add the necessary config to your files then *reload* nginx - this will cause it to check your config first before reloading and it'll let you know of any errors without taking your site offline.