# nginx - Truncate a field in the access log

Tags: nginx

Is there a way to truncate a field's contents that is stored in the access log?

I am interested in keeping only the first ten characters of User-Agent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you introduce a custom variable that contains the truncated user agent. For that you use the `map` directive on the regular user agent variable, `$http_user_agent`. The documentation for the map module is here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html. Then you configure the logging format using the `log_format` directive, see the documentation at https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/logging/. Finally, you tell the `access_log` to use your custom logging format.

In summary:

```
# ...
http {
    map $http_user_agent $trunc_agent {
        default "";
        "~*(?P<tr>.{0,10}).*" $tr;
    }
    log_format myformat '[other fields] "$trunc_agent"';
    access_log [logfile] myformat;
}
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks, but the document is silent on where to add the `map` directive. I tried to put it in /etc/nginx.conf and it says "map" directive is not allowed here.

Comment: That's strange -- I have just verified that the `map` instructions provided by `ngx_http_map_module` are included "out of the box" and no additional module configurations are loaded via `include` (on my machines). So putting them in `/etc/nginx.conf` SHOULD work. A search in this forum reveals that it should be enabled and installed by default: https://serverfault.com/questions/780778/enable-modules-on-nginx-and-ubuntu Do you have any custom compiled version? Or a hosting solution that disables some modules?

Comment: Oh, I got it to work by putting map as a block nested in http. (Earlier I was putting it on the same level as http.) But it always give me the value I have in default. I configured the log to show both the truncated version and the standard $http_user_agent and I can confirm that even if there is a user agent, the result of map is that default value. The documentation doesn't say much about the syntax for the `map` directive. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I should have provided a little more context. I had included all expressions at the same level (and that was meant to be inside the `http` section). I have clarified it in the edit. Furthermore, the regular expression was buggy -- I missed the `.*` at the end! I have now verified that the current form does what you asked for!